# Не сохраняет русские слова

Tags: php, mysql

При регистрации не сохраняются `lastname` и `firstname` (они на русском).
Помогите, пожалуйста.
[Код сохранения по этой ссылке.](http://fastunit.16mb.com/avatars/save.txt)

Answer (score 1):

Нужно задать кодировку подключения. После `mysql_connect()`.

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8', $db);
```

Comment: не работает

Comment: В какой кодировке php-файл?

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER DATABASE <database_name> CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

короче, ищи способ поменять кодировку

Comment: у меня и так utf8

Comment: тогда экранируй..

Comment: тоесть                   ___